# How do you split long lines of code in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I've just started using Verilog to code FIFO's and other complex logic. I was wondering how to split a long line of code in verilog (similar to say the \ in some languages like C?)

I have the following line of code which is incredibly long -

```
pushinl = (read_allow&(~pushinl))|(pushinl&read_allow&(~(stopout_a0&stopout_a1&stopout_a2))|(pushinl&read_allow&(stopout_a0&stopout_a1&stopout_a2));
```

I wasn't able to find any answers online that help with this problem in verilog. Is there a character used in verilog to split the above line?

I am using vi as my main editor. When I write this line of code as it is, I get the following syntax error:

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
  Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "fpam2.v", 150: token is ';'
                 |(pushinl&rctrl&(sout_a0&sout_a1&sout_a2));
                                                            ^

1 error
CPU time: .065 seconds to compile
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just give new line to OR(SOP) operator or AND(POS) operator, this gives you more readability and handy debugging.

```
pushinl = (read_allow & (~pushinl))
        | (pushinl & read_allow & (~(stopout_a0 & stopout_a1 & stopout_a2))
        | (pushinl & read_allow & (stopout_a0 & stopout_a1 & stopout_a2));
```

There is no special character of symbol like '\' is used in verilog.

Try this,

```
pushinl = (read_allow & (~pushinl))
        | (pushinl & read_allow & (~(stopout_a0 & stopout_a1 & stopout_a2)))
        | (pushinl & read_allow & (stopout_a0 & stopout_a1 & stopout_a2));
```

In second line there is missing of bracket.

Comment: I tried this, but I keep getting a token error. I'll give you more information about the error in just a sec.

Comment: Yup I tried your method right now. I'm still getting that token error. It's really weird...

Comment: can you upload code? I have again changed that line.

Comment: Hey Prakash, I solved it. I had a missing bracket in my code! Your style works though. Thanks a lot!